# I installed Ubuntu from USB drive, and when i booted from main HDD - ubuntu was in "try ubuntu or install ubuntu" AGAIN

Tags: boot, usb

It is a very old Laptop (DELL Inspiron 1501), i flashed on my USB drive Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS, and i choose safe graphics mode. I just want a working ubuntu on my laptop, nothing more. What ive done wrong or/and what should i do?

Comment: yes, it was my first thought about that

Comment: It's pretty simple: The "*Try Ubuntu or Install Ubuntu*" prompt appears **only** on the installer. Not on a properly-installed system. Therefore, either you are still running the USB installer or you somehow *copied* the installer onto your HDD instead of actually installing.

Comment: flashed an ubuntu on usb device using balena etcher - booted from this usb on laptop - did the installation process - rebooted the system - its in "try ubuntu or install ubuntu" mode - thought that maybe that im booting from usb again- shuted off the system - plugged off the usb - turned it on - still "try ubuntu or install ubuntu" mode

Comment: oh okey, i will try to do this again but more stricter, thanks

Comment: If older system you may need a light weight flavor. https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours
Light weight flavors:
Lubuntu, xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, Budgie
Flavors of Ubuntu only come with three years of supported life (five years applies to Ubuntu Desktop, Ubuntu Server but not flavors)
 I could not get Ubuntu to install to my 2006 Laptop (back with 20.04). But server version installed & I could add light weight gui. I also have used laptop with Kubuntu on external SSD, SSD was actually UEFI boot, but I just added a BIOS boot to laptops HDD & it worked. SSD made old laptop very functional.

Comment: Thanks! I`ll try that